# Adding an object in a object of arrays in Angular/Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add a object to an array of objects in firebase? 
I can create an array of objects with this code, but i can't add a object to it.

```
    return this.db.doc(`Users/${userCredential.user.uid}`).set({
      email: this.newUser.email,
      firstname: this.newUser.firstName,
      lastname: this.newUser.lastName,
      balance: this.newUser.balance,
      movimentos: [
        { valor: 69, tipo_movimento: 'Débito' },
        { valor: 19, tipo_movimento: 'Crédito' },
        { valor: 29, tipo_movimento: 'Débito' },
      ]
    })
  }
```

My attempt to adding an object in the array:

```
    return this.db.collection(`Users/${userKey}`).add({
      movimentos: [
        { valor: 6669, tipo_movimento: 'Débito' },
      ]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a **unique** object to an array, you can use the `array-union` operator.

```
this.db.doc(`Users/${userCredential.user.uid}`).update({
    movimentos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
        { valor: 69, tipo_movimento: 'Débito' },
        { valor: 19, tipo_movimento: 'Crédito' },
        { valor: 29, tipo_movimento: 'Débito' }
    )
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Firebase you have to update the entire object. As such you would need to extract the entire object, add a value in the array with .push() and then upload your object

Comment: Can you give an example of who can I extract the entire object?